# Rasterio: error when resampling a raster

Tags: python, numpy, rasterio

I'm trying to resample a Sentinel 2 band using an upscale factor. I'm using the code exactly as in [Rasterio documentation](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/resampling.html#up-and-downsampling) but I keep getting an error.

Here is my code:

```
import os
import rasterio
from rasterio.enums import Resampling

Workspace = '.../SnowCoverProject'
S2_path = os.path.join (Workspace, 'raw_data/S2B_MSIL2A_20191208T184749_N0213_R070_T11UNQ_20191208T205518.SAFE')

#Browse through the S2 product folder and retrieve Green and SWIR bands
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(S2_path):
    for name in files:
        if name.endswith("B03_10m.jp2"):
            Gpath = os.path.join (root, name)
        elif name.endswith("B11_20m.jp2"):
            SWIRpath = os.path.join (root, name)
        else:
            pass

#Read the bands as arrays. Resample (upscale) SWIR to 10m.
upscale_factor = 2
with rasterio.open(Gpath) as green:
    GREEN = green.read()

with rasterio.open(SWIRpath) as swir:
    # resample data to target shape
    SWIR = swir.read(out_shape=(swir.count, int(swir.width * upscale_factor), int(swir.height * upscale_factor)), resampling=Resampling.bilinear)
    # scale image transform
    transform = swir.transform * swir.transform.scale((swir.width / SWIR.shape\[-2\]),(swir.height / SWIR.shape\[-1\]))

ndsi= (GREEN.astype(float) - SWIR.astype(float)) / (GREEN+SWIR)

profile = GREEN.meta
profile.update(driver='GTiff')
profile.update(dtype=rasterio.float32)

NDSI = os.path.join (Workspace, 'NDSI.tif')
with rasterio.open(NDSI, 'w', **profile) as dst:
    dst.write(NDSI.astype(rasterio.float32))][1]
```

I'm getting this error:

```
TypeError: read() got an unexpected keyword argument 'resampling'
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are the backslashes in your code a typo? Where the `transform` var is set: `SWIR.shape\[-2\]`?

Comment: Is your `rasterio` version up to date?

Comment: @MarceloVilla, my Rasterio version is 0.36.0 . I'm running it in Python 2.7. I had to downgrade everything to solve the JP2000 GDAL support issues. Do I need to uprade it ?

Comment: @Ryan. Oh yes the backslashes is just a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved: I just needed to upgrade my Rasterio. Thanks.